# Редирект nginx если есть параметр get

Tags: nginx

Как при помощи *nginx* сделать редирект страниц,  у которых есть параметр `__hstc`?

Пример страниц:

```
/page/2/?__hstc=85203782.2a1e835c34ab7bf88e972fdd7a7debc8.1479686400000.1479686400000.1479686400000.1&__hssc=85203782.1.1479686400000&__hsfp=528229161
```

и

```
/someurl/?__hstc=85203782.2a1e835c34ab7bf88e972fdd7a7debc8.1479686400000.1479686400000.1479686400000.1&__hssc=85203782.1.1479686400000&__hsfp=528229161
```

Answer (score 0):

```
location / {
    if ($arg___hstc) {
        return 301 https://example.com;
    }
}
```

По [ссылке](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_arg_) читай подробнее про встроенные переменные.